# Getting the intersection of two owl expressions

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I need to get the intersection result of two expressions, more precisely, to check if the intersection is equal to an empty set. I tried by using the following code, but it returns just the expression of the intersection. If you have an idea how it can return the result of the intersection or cases with empty sets

```
OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
Set<OWLClassExpression> Set = new HashSet<OWLClassExpression>();
Set.add(e.getNNF());
Set.add(e.getComplementNNF());
System.out.println(" the intersection is : "+factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(Set));
```

Thank you

Comment: Your question is confusing. There is a difference between creating an OWL class expression and getting its extension, i.e. the individuals that belong to the class expression. The intersection of two class expressions is indeed itself a class expression, thus, the same holds here. You have to use a reasoner to get the set of instances of the class expression. Then you can check whether this set is empty or not.

Comment: That's not effectively what I need. If you remember in the previous question, when I used visitor, I was looking for class expressions that contain complementOf ( for example : Vegetarian is equivalent to the intersection of animal eats ComplementOf(Animal) ). I need to get such cases since they contain ComplementOf(Class) or by using condition I want to eliminate them. So, I thought that the intersection of the class expression and its complement will give an empty set based on the mathematical formula :  A∩ ComplementOF(A) =∅.

Comment: But I don't think that works, since as you said when I get the list of classes I'll get only classes (in the example it's Animal) I can't get the empty set anyway.

Comment: "the intersection of the class expression and its complement will give an empty set" -> that is formally **not** correct. The interpretation of this will result in an empty set. I still don't get what you're after and what you use case is. Considering your example, `Vegetarian EquivalentTo Animal and eats some (not Animal)` - what would be the intersection here based on?

Comment: supposing that A= Vegetarian EquivalentTo Animal and eats some (not Animal) and ∁(A) = ComplementOf(Vegetarian EquivalentTo Animal and eats some (not Animal)), by this way :   A∩∁(A)=∅.

Comment: Anyway, this won't resolve my problem to get class Expressions containing not(Class) as for the example not(Animal).

Comment: I don't understand why parsing the class expression doesn't work if you're looking for the occurrences of `not(A)`

Comment: In fact, you gave me the solution since your first comment, which is parsing the class expression. But I didn't understand what you meant. now it's done for this part of not(A). I don't have to skip those cases. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to verify is whether the intersection of the two class expressions is satisfiable, I believe - meaning if the intersection *can* have instances. For this, you need a reasoner, where you can use the `isSatisfiable()` method does the job.

Comment: So you propose - as AKSW said-  to get classes of the two class expressions and then verifying if the intersection of the sets is satisfiable ? Something like this : if(reasoner.isSatisfiable(factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(mySet)))

Comment: Yes that's my suggestion

Comment: Thank you very much for helping